# reverse engineer not update new Objetcs Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, reverse-engineering, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I Have a problem. I using Oracle Data Modeler. I did reverse engineer for generate physical model.

I'm using Oracle Data Modeler. I did reverse engineering to generate physical model. When I made the changes in the database and wanted to update the model. There came the new objects, only the modification of old objects.

I have solution of this problem ?. thank you

I using: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production SQL Developer: Versão 4.0.0.13 Build MAIN-13.80

Thank's

Comment: it's assumed your design has all the objects you want when you do the first reverse engineer, and that all new ones will be built in the design tool - so it doesn't pick them up. you need to do a another RE to pick up the new objects

Comment: Thank's thatjeffsmith. when I make a new import objects I get those created after I create the model ..